# SQL sum numbers in text

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, text, sum

This is the code

```
select 'QWXWX/50,GNTGHNT/5,F/500'
```

I want to see sum of the numbers in this texts. My expectation result is 555.

Comment: Just don't do this in T-SQL; it's a **terrible** language to attempt this in. Use something that has *good* string manipulation tools.

Comment: I agree, but sometimes you just need to do operations over sql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't do this in T-SQL, but anyway you still could if you wanted to:

```
with basedata (data) as 
(
  select * from string_split('QWXWX/50,GNTGHNT/5,F/500',',')
)
select sum(cast(replace(data, rtrim(translate(data, '0123456789',space(10))), '') as int))  from basedata;
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=916da5db20e846034595efba2dba42f4)

Answer (score 1):

A different approach using a tally to replace the non-numerical characters and comma with nothing, and then split the string and aggregate it. I include both an `nvarchar` and `varchar` pattern splitter here, but use the `varchar` one in the solution:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.PatternNCharacterReplace (@String nvarchar(4000), @Pattern nvarchar(100), @ReplacementCharacter nvarchar(1)) 
RETURNS table
AS RETURN
    WITH N AS(
        SELECT N
        FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
    Tally AS(
        SELECT TOP(LEN(@String))
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
        FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4)  --4096 rows; For a varchar(8000) or MAX you would need more rows for such lengths
    SELECT STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN V.C LIKE @Pattern THEN @ReplacementCharacter ELSE V.C END,'') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY T.I) AS ReplacedString
    FROM Tally T
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(@String,T.I,1)))V(C);
GO


CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.PatternCharacterReplace (@String varchar(8000), @Pattern varchar(100), @ReplacementCharacter varchar(1)) 
RETURNS table
AS RETURN
    WITH N AS(
        SELECT N
        FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
    Tally AS(
        SELECT TOP(LEN(@String))
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
        FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4)  --10000 rows;
    SELECT STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN V.C LIKE @Pattern THEN @ReplacementCharacter ELSE V.C END,'') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY T.I) AS ReplacedString
    FROM Tally T
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(@String,T.I,1)))V(C);
GO
SELECT SUM(TRY_CONVERT(int, SS.[value]))
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY dbo.PatternCharacterReplace(YT.YourString, '[^0-9,]', '') PCR
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(PCR.ReplacedString, ',') SS
GROUP BY YT.ID; --Grouping in case you have multiple values. This may well be against a scalar value, so this wouldn't be needed
```

This does, interesting, appear to be faster that Cetin's solution with `TRIM`: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=246759ff67f46f106ab56c55f7bf57fc)

Comment: Sure, if I wanted to and care I could write a much faster one using a CLR function :)

Comment: Honestly, I was expected this solution to be *slower* than yours, @CetinBasoz . Just reminds me how expensive `REPLACE` and `TRANSLATE` can be at times. I don't disagree, [this that shouldn't be done in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73120823/sql-sum-numbers-in-text/73121264?noredirect=1#comment129142609_73120823) though.